# Using a custom trained huggingface tokenizer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface, huggingface-hub

I’ve trained a custom tokenizer using a custom dataset using this [code](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/quicktour) that’s on the documentation. Is there a method for me to add this tokenizer to the hub and to use it as the other tokenizers by calling the AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained() function? If I can’t do that how can I use the tokenizer to train a custom model from scratch?
Thanks for your help!!!

Here's the code below:

```
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.models import BPE
tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE(unk_token="[UNK]"))

from tokenizers.trainers import BpeTrainer
trainer = BpeTrainer(special_tokens=["[UNK]", "[CLS]", "[SEP]", "[PAD]", "[MASK]"])

from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import Whitespace
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Whitespace()

folder = 'dataset_unicode'
files = [f"/content/drive/MyDrive/{folder}/{split}.txt" for split in ["test", "train", "valid"]]
tokenizer.train(files, trainer)

from tokenizers.processors import TemplateProcessing
tokenizer.post_processor = TemplateProcessing(
    single="[CLS] $A [SEP]",
    pair="[CLS] $A [SEP] $B:1 [SEP]:1",
    special_tokens=[
        ("[CLS]", tokenizer.token_to_id("[CLS]")),
        ("[SEP]", tokenizer.token_to_id("[SEP]")),
    ],
)

# I've tried saving it like this but it doesn't work as I expect it:
tokenizer.save("data/tokenizer-custom.json")
```

Comment: Please follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75990055/6664872) to load it. You can afterward save it with `save_pretrained` and upload it to the hub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AutoTokenizer` expects a few files in the directory:

```
awesometokenizer/
    tokenizer_config.json
    special_tokens_map.json
    tokenizer.json
```

But the default `tokenizer.Tokenizer.save()` function only saves the vocab file in `awesometokenizer/tokenizer.json`, open up the json file and compare the `['model']['vocab']` keys to your json from `data/tokenizer-custom.json`.

The simplest way to let `AutoTokenizer` load `.from_pretrained` is to follow the answer that @cronoik posted in the comment, using `PreTrainedTokenizerFast`, i.e. adding a few lines to your existing code:

```
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.models import BPE
from tokenizers.trainers import BpeTrainer
from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import Whitespace
from tokenizers.processors import TemplateProcessing

from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast  # <---- Add this line.



trainer = BpeTrainer(special_tokens=["[UNK]", "[CLS]", "[SEP]", "[PAD]", "[MASK]"])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE(unk_token="[UNK]"))
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Whitespace()

files = ["big.txt"]  # e.g. training with https://norvig.com/big.txt
tokenizer.train(files, trainer)

tokenizer.post_processor = TemplateProcessing(
    single="[CLS] $A [SEP]",
    pair="[CLS] $A [SEP] $B:1 [SEP]:1",
    special_tokens=[
        ("[CLS]", tokenizer.token_to_id("[CLS]")),
        ("[SEP]", tokenizer.token_to_id("[SEP]")),
    ],
)

# Add these lines:
#     |
#     |
#     V
awesome_tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(tokenizer_object=tokenizer)
awesome_tokenizer.save_pretrained("awesome_tokenizer")
```

Then you can load the trained tokenizer:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

auto_loaded_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    "awesome_tokenizer", 
    local_files_only=True
)
```

**Note:** `tokenizers` though can be pip installed, is a library in Rust with Python bindings

Answer (score 0):

The AutoTokenizer anticipates the presence of specific files in the directory structure:

```
my_tokenizer/
    tokenizer_config.json
    special_tokens_map.json
    tokenizer.json
```

However, when you save the tokenizer using `tokenizer.save("token_file_only.json")`, only a single JSON file is saved, which cannot be directly loaded. Nonetheless, you can load the tokenizer for use in your project with the following code: `tokenizer = Tokenizer.from_file("token_file_only.json")`.

If you intend to use the tokenizer with `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained()`, you need to follow these steps:

```py
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast, AutoTokenizer
from tokenizers import Tokenizer, models
# other imports

# Initialize and train the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(models.BPE())
# Train the tokenizer...

# Save the tokenizer json file only
# tokenizer.save("token_file_only.json")

# Convert the tokenizer to a fast tokenizer
my_tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(tokenizer_object=tokenizer)

# Save the converted tokenizer for AutoTokenizer
my_tokenizer.save_pretrained("my_tokenizer")

# Now you can use the tokenizer with AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained()
loaded_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("my_tokenizer")
```

This way, you save the necessary files in the `my_tokenizer` directory, making it compatible with `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained()`.

For more into Tokenizer: [See Documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/en/quicktour#:%7E:text=Training%20the%20tokenizer&text=Start%20with%20all%20the%20characters,reached%20the%20size%20we%20want.)